# Using LEN within VarChar in a CAST statement

Tags: t-sql

I'm setting up an Audit Case statement and want to capture the LEN of the field contents in the VarChar() - TSQL doesn't seem to like me doing it that way, does anyone have a simple solution for this - thanks in advance!

Ex: VarChar(Len(a.areacode))

Using MS-SQL 2016

```
CASE WHEN LEN(a.areacode) > 3 THEN CAST(a.areacode as VarChar(Len(a.areacode)))
ELSE CAST(LEFT(a.areacode,3) as VarChar(3))
END AS areacode
```

Comment: A query will return a column of a single data type for the result set.  I am not sure why you want to change the length and if that will really solve the issue you have.  If you really want to limit the result set to the smallest possible type an idea would be to first determine the max length for that field in the current dataset, create a table (maybe temporary) with dynamic sql and then fill it with insert tablename select ...

Comment: Using Varchar as your datatype means you do not have to worry about the length. Just make it sufficiently large and you should be fine. If that does not make sense, please explain further what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, let me be more clear.

Comment: Thanks guys, I ended up redesigning and creating a flag for the fields that were in error.